# Android NoClassDefFound when referencing class from external libraries (IntelliJ IDEA 12)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm having an issue with IntelliJ's dependency handling in regards to external modules. Here's some context:

I'm writing an Android app which implements Google Maps. For my current feature set, I require two external libraries-- Google's Play Services Library and mapex (A third party google map extension library located here https://code.google.com/p/mapex/). I actually built most of this project in Android Studio before I was recommended to move to IntelliJ due to the easier dependency handling. But now I'm here and still having problems.

---

## My Error

When trying to build an object from a class located in the mapex package (com.androidnatic.maps), I get this error when starting the activity the view is contained in (object has not been created yet):

> 07-03 11:40:35.837: ERROR/dalvikvm(3585): Could not find class 'com.androidnatic.maps.SimpleMapView', referenced from method com.example.myproject.MapActivity.showHeatMap

And then, upon creation, my app force closes and leaves this behind in logcat:

> 7-03 11:40:45.467: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.androidnatic.maps.SimpleMapView
>           at com.example.myproject.MapActivity.showHeatMap(MapActivity.java:492)

Yet I'm completely stumped because my IDE gives me *no sign that anything is wrong!* Classes are auto-filled in when trying to access them from MyProject.

[ide-fill-in http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/fillin.jpg](http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/fillin.jpg)

No build errors about missing classes, missing modules, class definitions, or anything related.

I get the same results if I try to access the class via its full package name as well.

```
// No dice.
final SimpleMapView mapView = new SimpleMapView(this, "apikey");
final com.androidnatic.maps.SimpleMapView mapView = new com.androidnatic.maps.SimpleMapView(this, "apikey");
```

It seems that there's only an issue when the application is running on my phone, as far as my IDE is concerned.

---

Here's the structure of MyProject:
[main-project-structure http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/mainstructure.jpg](http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/mainstructure.jpg)

Here's my main project's dependency settings (where I assume I screwed up somewhere):
[project-structure http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/projectstructure.jpg](http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/projectstructure.jpg)

And here is the structure of the mapex library module:
[mapex-lib http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/mapexstructure.jpg](http://www.tonyandrys.com/img/mapexstructure.jpg)

The class files that I'm trying to access live in MapExLib/gen and MapExLib/src, which are currently marked as source directories (blue).

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Comment: `File->Invalidate caches` and try again.

Comment: Just tried this: `File -> Invalidate Caches`, IntelliJ restarted, `Build -> Rebuild Project`, then ran MyProject but unfortunately it didn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: Sorry. Your setup looks OK to me.  Hope someone else comes along..

Comment: Thanks for the help in any case! Maybe invalidating caches could help someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :
[Android, IntelliJ Idea, changing module type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466044/android-intellij-idea-changing-module-type)

I had the same error *"Could not find class XXX from referenced method XXX"* with Intellij, involving an Android Test Module and a test which could not find the Activity class anywhere.
I set inside the **Project Structure** the main Module's **Facet Android** to **Library Module** (checkbox) and it worked...

Let us know