# Android, IntelliJ Idea, changing module type

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I'm getting the following message.

android-validator: Suspicious module dependency com.package.name -> ProjectName: Android application module depends on other application module. Possibly, you should change type of module 'ProjectName' to 'Library' or change the dependency scope to 'Provided'.

How can I change the type of a module??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to File -> Project structure -> Modules, select the desired module, click on the arrow to expand the module, you'll see “Android”. Click on it, you see on the right: “Facet 'Android'” and a checkbox “Library module”

Comment: where is the arrow on Android Studio 2.2.1?

Answer (score 4):

1. go to your build.gradle from your module
2. replace your `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
3. sync the project

Comment: Thank you this was it